# При реализации метода Хаффмана выскакивает исключение: Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. root было 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

Здравствуйте! 
Разбираюсь с методом Хаффмана в Visual Studio, язык C++. Выскакивает исключение:нарушение доступа для чтения. root было 0xCDCDCDCD. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int a;
    char c;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node()
    {
    }

    Node(Node *L, Node *R)
    {
        left = L;
        right = R;
        a = L->a + R->a;
    }
};

struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(Node* l, Node* r) const
    {
        return l->a < r->a;
    }
};

vector<bool> code;
map<char, vector<bool> > table;

void BuildTable(Node *root)
{
    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        code.push_back(0);
        BuildTable(root->left);
    }

    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        code.push_back(1);
        BuildTable(root->right);
    }

    if (root->c)
        table[root->c] = code;

    code.pop_back();
}

int main()
{
    string s = "it is my striiiiing!!!!";
    map<char, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        m[c]++ ;
    }

    list<Node*> t;

    map<char, int>::iterator i;
    for (i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
    {
        Node *p = new Node; 
        p->c = i->first;
        p->a = i->second;
        t.push_back(p);
    }

    while (t.size() != 1)
    {
        t.sort(MyCompare());

        Node *SonL = t.front();
        t.pop_front();
        Node *SonR = t.front();
        t.pop_front();

        Node *parent = new Node(SonL, SonR);
        t.push_back(parent);
    }

    Node *root = t.front();

    BuildTable(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        vector<bool> x = table[c];

        for (int n = 0; n < x.size(); n++)
            cout << x[n];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка возникает вот на этом месте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите место, в котром возникает исключение. Вы ничего не сказали по проблеме, которая у Вас есть. Предлагаю отправить вопрос на доработку.

Comment: 0xCDCDCDCD означает неинициализированную память   http://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/276994

Comment: Прикрепила изображение с ошибкой

Answer (score 2):

- После создания `Node *p = new Node;` поля `p->left` и `p->right` содержат мусор. Т.е. все якобы "листовые" узлы дерева содержат мусор в указателях `left` и `right`.
- Нелистовые узлы дерева содержат мусор в поле `c`.
- В вашей функции `BuildTable` вызовы `code.push_back()` делаются столько раз, сколько есть ссылок `parent -> child` в дереве. А вот `code.pop_back()` вызывается столько раз, сколько есть *узлов* в дереве. То есть `code.pop_back()` вызывается на один раз больше, чем `code.push_back()`.